# Checking server status with pymongo with timeout

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a monitoring script check up on our mongodb instance once per minute, and need a good way to connect, perform a simple query and have it either return within 10 seconds or simply timeout in some predictable way if it takes more than 10 seconds and let me catch that error/exception.

According to pymongo's documentation, you cannot set the query timeout, only the socket and connection timeout (which seems to be working fine). Is there any workaround to this?

The flow of the program is this:

1. Connect to mongodb
2. Perform a simple `find()` query to check for the last updated document (used for statistics)
3. Close the connection.

#1 always works fine, but the entire request times out at #2 with no way for me to catch it within my own self-imposed 10 second limit.

The lock seems to happen during peak hours because of a number of concurrent map-reduce queries. We are using mongodb 2.4.3.

Comment: if this is an indexed find() it should be completing way faster than timeout, especially since you're only querying for a single record!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [socketTimeoutMS](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html?highlight=socketTimeoutMS#pymongo.mongo_client) when you create your **mongo_client** or you can add it to your **find**.

For example, in the following code , I connect to the local mongod and then simulate a long running query with the 10 second sleep in the $where function (not recommended) . The 1 second socketTimeoutMS causes the call to fail with **pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: timed out** :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
if client.test.ing.count() == 0:
  client.test.ing.insert({})
client.test.ing.find( { '$where' : 'function() { sleep(10000); return True; }' } , socketTimeoutMS=1000).count()
```

I hope that helps.

**Note 1 : if the collection is empty then the client returns immediately**

**Note 2 : if you just get the cursor and don't do anything then you won't get an error**

Comment: The thing is, the socket is not slow. It's the database itself, which means the connect, send query and (eventually) receive query is fast on the socket. It's the query, after sending it to the server, that takes a long time. `socketTimeoutMS` does not alter this. pymongo does mention the cursor timeout, but apparently in python a timeout is not supported for it (I have seen it in PHP and other language)